# nonsurjectivity of Banach-Stone theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

Currently I'm studying the extension of Banach-Stone theorem using this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584880406). There is one section about the removal of surjectivity of the isometric isomorphism between the two function spaces $C(K)$ and $C(Q)$. Before the main theorem, several lemmas are established. These lemmas all revolve around the dual spaces and and extreme points of convex set. I have no idea what is the definition of extreme point of convex set. Can anyone recommend me some references  on extreme point of convex set?

Comment: have you googled what extreme point is?

Comment: @Norbert: Yes, but I would like to study more about it,like some related results.

Comment: Then you need to look for papres and books on Chouqet theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classic theorem involving extreme points of convex sets is the Krein Milman theorem.  If you're looking to learn about this topic in relation to the Banach Stone theorem, the Krein Milman theorem is a good place to start, and there are many references on the web; e.g. a quick google search came up with [this](http://www.math.caltech.edu/simon_chp8.pdf), which seems to be at the level of what you're asking for.